# Internet on android, causing twitter4j exception?

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I'm experimenting with twitter4j on android (new to both) coded up a simple process in java just to test it out. It downloads a users timeline and prints to screen.

I modify the code for android, but I get a TwitterException when i try to download the user timeline. I checked out the debugger and the exception is null; no information given. I've also added the Internet permission to the android manifest on previous advice. Heres the code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;


import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Test2 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        List<Status> statuses = null;
        Twitter api = new TwitterFactory().getInstance("USERNAME","PASSWORD");

        try{
         statuses = api.getUserTimeline();
        }
        catch(TwitterException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        for(Status s: statuses){
            System.out.println(s.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

I realise this only prints to the console, just to keep it simple.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Any1 new coming over this Thread, doing it this way is deprecated. You should check out this new Tutorial: http://goo.gl/99vpL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the `INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Also `System.out.println()` is not recommended on Android. Please use the `android.util.Log` class and send your debugging output to LogCat (available via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Please check your timestamp. Each HttpRequest contain current timestamp, if the timestamp is wrong then it throw exception.